# Export result from FIND command to variable value in linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I try to complete one shell script, but I don't have idea how to do final, and probably easiest step.

That is attaching value to variable from find command.

For example, if I execute:

```
find -type f -iname *test.tdf*
```

I will get output in example:

```
/root/Desktop/test.tdf
```

Now, I need a way to attach that value to for example:

```
export PATH_TO_TEST_TDF_FILE=/root/Desktop/test.tdf
```

But now, problem is that file may not be located there, so I must assign it to result from find.

How?

Answer (score 6):

If your `find` invocation outputs a single file along the lines of what you have shown, [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x219.html) should do the trick

```
export PATH_TO_TEST_TDF_FILE="$(find . -type f -iname '*test.tdf*')"
```

Or, as [BroSlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3076724/broslow) points out,

```
export PATH_TO_TEST_TDF_FILE="$(find . -type f -iname '*test.tdf*' -print -quit)"
```

to have `find` quit after the first file

Comment: @1_CR You probably want to add `-print` `-quit` here, so it stops after finding one since behavior doesn't make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Would be PATH_TO_TEST_TDF_FILE="$(find -type f -iname *test.tdf*)" but probably doesn't work too well as find returns more than one file most of the time.

Pro tip: The results of find should be assumed to not fit in a variable until proven otherwise.